# Angular 5: how to download pdf using Service worker

Tags: javascript, angular5, service-worker, jspdf, angular-service-worker

I am using `JsPdf` to generate and download pdf on the client side. 
Unfortunately this process hung the browser for a while.

So my question is how can I generate and download pdf on the background, using `service worker` ?

Answer (score 1):

**Service worker is not the right place -** Service workers are like proxy server. All your requests in scope passes though it and can be cached. On the other side, JSPDF is a client side library which our browser had to execute and generate the PDF file and depending on various factors like data size, client hardware, effectiveness of the library itself, it may impact the browser performance.

[**Web Workers**](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) - Web workers also runs the tasks in a separate thread(like service worker), which will reduce the impact of browser load in user interaction with the web page, by not loading up with the main thread handing user interaction.

**In case you consider server side PDF generation -** When ever you go via service worker, you are caching that response data, which eventually fills up the limited quota each app has. And since such download scenarios are not common use case for caching, doing a regular AJAX call to generate PDF in server side and download to client side is on option to consider.